# how to bind search data to table in angular

Tags: angular

I have a page on which i am showing user names in table. On each page i am requesting an api to display only 5 users to each page. I have implement search filter. That is when i search user it search from database and give the result. In my case i am able to search use but not able to bind user to the table.

*my component.html* code

```
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText1" 
       (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)"/>
      <table class="table tabs">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S. No.</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Customer Address</th>
         
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        
        <tr
          *ngFor="
            let cam of getCamListPay
              | filter: searchText1
              | paginate
                : {
                    itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage,
                    currentPage: currentPage,
                   
                  };
            let i = index
          "
        >
          <td>{{(currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage + i + 1}}</td>
          <td>{{ cam?.Customer.Name }}</td>
          <td>{{ cam.Address }}</td>
                    
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

*my component.ts* code

```
 ngOnInit(){
this.fetchUser();
 }

    onSearchChange(event){
this.service.filterCustomerName(event).subscribe((result:any)=>{     
  this.searchText1 = event
  this.fetchUser() 
})
}
fetchUser(){
 if (this.searchText) {
  this.cam_service
    .cameraListPagination('', '', this.searchText).subscribe((res: 
  any) => {
      console.log(res)
      this.getCamListPay = res.payload;
      console.log(this.getCamListPay)
      console.log(typeof(this.getCamListPay))
    })
   }
  else{
 this.cam_service
    .cameraListPagination(this.currentPage, this.itemsPerPage, 
   this.searchText)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
     
      this.getCamListPay = res.payload.data;
      console.log(this.getCamListPay)     
    });

  }
   }
```

In my console i am able to see filtered data. But dont know why it is not binding to the table.
giving the following error
[image]

Comment: why do you have a filter in ngFor as well?

Comment: then how can i filter user

Comment: don't you get a filtered list from API?

Comment: I think this might be an issue with reference. Since "getCamListPay " is am array of objects you need to refresh it's reference. You can use slice()

Comment: getCamListPay.filter(x=>x.Name==searchText1)

Comment: Use angular searching with resources mat table.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this.
I think this is due to reference issue, since arrays are reference variables.

```
onSearchChange(event){
   this.service.filterCustomerName(event).subscribe((result:any)=>{     
     this.searchText1 = event;
     fetchUser();   
   })
}

fetchUser(){
 if (this.searchText) {
  this.cam_service
    .cameraListPagination('', '', this.searchText).subscribe((res: 
  any) => {
      console.log(res)
      this.getCamListPay = res.payload.slice();
      console.log(this.getCamListPay)
      console.log(typeof(this.getCamListPay))
    })
   }
  else{
 this.cam_service
    .cameraListPagination(this.currentPage, this.itemsPerPage, 
   this.searchText)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
     
      this.getCamListPay = res.payload.data.slice();
      console.log(this.getCamListPay)     
    });

  }
   }
```

Or you can use spread operator

Comment: No its not working.. giving me  this error "result.data.slice is not a function".

Comment: can you share some refrences??

Comment: Use slice where you assign value to *getCamListPay*.
For example inside "fetchUser()" ,   use  this.getCamListPay = res.payload.slice(); instead of this.getCamListPay = res.payload;